# Logging warning not showing with command line script using local version of Dask

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

This code works for me in Jupyter notebook, but fails to intercept the warning message when I run it from the command line (Centos 7):

```
import io
import logging
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

def vc_delayed( df_file ):
    f = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stderr(f):
        ddf = dd.read_csv( df_file, compression='lz4', dtype=str, blocksize=None, 
                          error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True )
        if f.getvalue():
            logging.warning( f'For {df_file}: {f.getvalue()}' )

    ddf = ddf[ cols ].map_partitions(pd.DataFrame.replace, {np.NaN: "_NULL_"})
    return ddf.map_partitions( vc_func ).to_delayed()

res = map( vc_delayed, myfiles )
out = dask.compute( *res, scheduler='processes' )
```

Which produces this Jupyter notebook output (expected):

```
 WARNING:root:For /data/user/datafu/broker_countz/further_split/further_split_aba.csv.lz4: b'Skipping line 5: expected 354 fields, saw 355\n'

[########################################] | 100% Completed |  4.5s
```

What is not expected is why this fails to output the warning as a Python 3 script executed from the command line.  The "original" pandas warning message pops up about the expected number of fields, but the stderr redirection seems to have failed since the modification is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Dask doesn't do anything fancy here.  It just runs your code in different threads.

My first guess would be an environment mismatch.  Perhaps check `sys.executable` in Jupyter and `which python` on the command line?